# node.js C++ addons to do all major computations

Tags: c++, node.js, web

A major limitation of node.js is its single threaded execution and the fact that JS is slow with computations.

What are the advantages/drawbacks of [using C++](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) to do the application's heavy lifting while using node as "glue code"? Obviously there are security risks using C++, but let's assume for the sake of argument that the C++ code is well-tested and perfect.

Comment: "security risks using C++"? What do you mean? Any non well-tested code can be faulty, but here you seem to imply that C++ is more prone to cause bigger issues

Comment: Buffer overflows and other memory issues are relevant with C++ unlike Javascript. What if the C++ code produces some edge case that dumps some sensitive data, accidentally? I'm just saying this before someone else does as a rebuttal. I'm not actually worried about my C++ code doing something stupid.

Comment: Well of course, but you should know how to prevent these issues if you want to develop anything in C++, so I still see this premise as falsy

Comment: recommended reading: **[What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this answer, I'll assume that the C++ code is ONLY well-tested and perfect security wise. If if would be actually be **perfect** then you wouldn't have asked this question anyways...

This is a general compilation of the first things that came to my head, not a complete list.

### **technical *disadvantages*** of using C++:

(or basically any external language addon)

- Communication:
  You will have to deal with any communication happening between your nodeapp and the C++-Code on your own. Any results will probably have to go through some sort of dispatcher in node, which can be problematic, if the message types are very heterogenous.
- Interoperability:
  There is a good chance, you will run in os-compatibility problems when using c++. Since C++ has to be compiled, there is a good chance, that after optimizing your build process for a certain operating system, you will have a hard time migrating it to another. This could especially be problematic if you are not hosting your own server, but use PaaS Provider.
- A bigger code base:
  Maintenance and Debugging *can* (bad code-style can make this even harder) become way more painful, if the code-base stretches over more (and maybe even distributed) systems.

### **social *disadvantages***:

- You have a split code base and will either have to hire developers which are able to develop good javascript AND C++ code (which could prove to be problematic) or hire separate developers, which is more expensive and one developer can not as easily step in for another if he/she is absent.

### **technical *advantages***:

- A wider range of libraries. You are not confined to node/js-libraries anymore, but can use all C++ libraries now, too. There are many libraries, which have no equal in js. Especially complex math- or scientific-libraries in general, are very hard to implement in js, due to the underlying language.
- Faster computation itself. Unless there is a major overhead in management and communication with C++, there is a good chance, that computational intensive use-cases can benefit from C++.
- Since C-Languages are closer to the hardware than higher-abstracted systems like js or node, you can in most cases optimize your software better for the task at hand.
- As you can better optimize, you can also use more advanced parallelization. This could either be local computing or even massive HPC (e.g. with OpenMP, MPI...). A framework for scientifical computation would be interesting for this.

### **social *advantages***:

- since node and C++ are not tightly coupled, you can outsource the C++ development to another, more specialized company and just provide them with the necessary interfaces. (you should, of course have these in place anyways, but there is a good chance that your average code base is not as modular as you want it to be :-))
- Finding and hiring specialized people could be easier. Even though it can be hard to find developers who are adept with node AND scientific computing in C++, its probably easier to find specialized people, who are for example very good at parallelization or statistical computation in C++ (or any other, more specialized language like R)

Again, this is not a complete list, just a few things that came to my head. Also, this is not really C++ specific, but rather generic, for any external addon.

Comment: Thanks Ben, this helped me gather my thoughts about the problem. My application domain requires heavy IO -- calls to multiple database servers and posix sockets. Should I only put the db calls and the like in C++ and not JS/node? I know (from experience) it's 10x more stressful to do sql in C++ than dynamic langs, but surely the C++ libs will be faster than the "emulation layers" on npm...what do you think?

Comment: This depends on your exact setup and where the biggest bottleneck is located.

Comment: If (as it is under normal circumstances) the actual bottleneck is the speed of the DB itself, rather than the querying service, it would probably not make a difference from where you call it, unless there is some extreme communication overhead between your C++ and NodeApp. 
For this, you should be able to build a simple benchmark and see how your system performs on one end or the other. As mentioned, I am convinced that there will not be a big difference, though

Answer (score 4):

I do not exactly know what you mean by security risks, with the need to typecheck passed parameters using the `is*` methods on arguments or obtaining the value representation using the [`v8::Value`](http://izs.me/v8-docs/classv8_1_1Value.html), the passed arguments are quite safe to work with.

If you are afraid of manual memory management and consider that a risk (which is not even that scary anymore, with `std::move` and RAII), then perhaps C++ module is not the way to go, until you learn to do so properly.

But to the question. The main advantage is, it is C++, and as you have already kind of mentioned, well written C++ code will reward you with sheer speed.

I have only tried the Node.js C++ addons for very simple data operations, so I cannot speak for an enterprise-size application, but from the experience I have had, the development is pretty straightforward and fairly easy to implement.

The main disadvantage? It is C++. C++ is by no mean an easy programming language. Although the new standards make it more and more developer friendly, it is still very complicated.

Other than that, there is not really an issue with gluing the two codebases (JavaScript and C++) together and if you know C++, just go ahead and try it for yourself.

Comment: to be fair, javascript isn't exactly a super simple language, with just as many (if not more) gotchas than C++. The issue generally is education - you have to spend as much time learning one as the other, too bad most people learn one and then think they can do a quick bodge job using the other.

Comment: @gbjbaanb You are right that JavaScript is not an easy language to grasp either. Although, it (nearly) always seems like the thing people are the most afraid when developing in C/C++ is the manual memory management and pointers, which JavaScript does not have.